# "Ambitious to [infinitive]" vs. "ambitious about [gerund]"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, infinitives, gerunds

What is the correct preposition to use with ambitious?

> 1. I am ambitious to achieve success.
> 2. I am ambitious about achieving success.

Comment: *About*. <chars>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are prepositions fixed for words?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8114/are-prepositions-fixed-for-words) which suggests  *I have the ambition to succeed,
I have an ambition for greatness*

Comment: jwpat7's comment is the right answer: it's "ambition to", not "ambitious to" or "about".

Answer (score 1):

*About* is possible, but so, too, is  *for*.

Comment: @JeffSahol: Hmmm, I'd say that there 'to' was not so much a preposition as an infinitive marker.

Comment: yipes, barrie...I was too ambitious there.

Answer (score 1):

As ambitious is an adjective, it rarely needs any preposition at all.

An ambitious man.
An ambitious concept.
An ambitious goal.

If you must have one, 'of' and 'for' are possible but also obsolete.

In your sentences, "I am ambitious" would cover it, or "my ambition is to succeed/achieve success"